# Variable Update in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, linked-list

I am learning about Linked Lists and was looking at this solution for a problem:

```
   /**
   * Definition for singly-linked list.
   * function ListNode(val, next) {
   *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
   *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
   * }
   */
   /**
   * @param {ListNode} list1
   * @param {ListNode} list2
   * @return {ListNode}
   */
   var mergeTwoLists = function(list1, list2) {
      let list = new ListNode();
      let head = list;
      console.log("first", head);
      while (list1 && list2) {
          if (list1.val <= list2.val) {
              list.next = list1;
              console.log("second", head);
              list1 = list1.next;
          } else {
              list.next = list2;
              list2 = list2.next;
          }
          list = list.next;
      }
      console.log("third", head, list);
      return head.next;
   };
```

There is one thing I can not understand. So, the "head" is set to track the "list". How come in the end the they have different values?

Comment: you're moving head to head->next. what you expect ?

Comment: According to your Code i would expect the following of your third console.log(): `Head` will return the first Node in your linked list while `List` is the last Node in your linked list, therefore they should be different. Unless, there is only 1 node added, then they might be identical.

Answer (score 0):

At first, "head" store the first node address. As "list" move along the linked list by passing different node address to "list", the result is they are different at the end. The "head" or "list" are just an address container, so they are not expected to be the same all the time. If they store the same address, they the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
let head = list;
```

In the above statement, the variable head holds the current value of the list and is not the reference to the list.

```
while (list1 && list2) {
      if (list1.val <= list2.val) {
          list.next = list1;
          console.log("second", head);
          list1 = list1.next;
      } else {
          list.next = list2;
          list2 = list2.next;
      }
      list = list.next;
  }
```

In the above loop, on every iteration the value of the list changes, it will not impact the value of the head.

So, in the end, since **head** holds the initial address it prints the entire list of values, and **list** prints the current value of the list (the last node).

See above image
[image]

here head -> [5, 7, 2, 15]
list -> [15]

Comment: What do you mean? the initial value of the list is not what is being printed on head by the end. There is one console.log printing head in the beginning and another in the end, the value is not the same.

Comment: head -> initial node address. so when you print it you all the values.

Answer (score 0):

> So, the "head" is set to track the "list". How come in the end the they have different values?

The reason is that `head` never is assigned anything else after its first initialisation, while `list` **is** assigned something else in the loop. `list` initially is referencing the same (dummy) node as `head`, but then later starts referencing different nodes by doing `list = list.next` repeatedly.

It may help to visualise this. Let's say we merge two lists with values 1, 4 and 2, 3 respectively:

First we have the initialisation happening. Just before the loop starts, we have this siutation:

```
head list
  ↓   ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val:  0   │
│ next:null │
└───────────┘

list1
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  1   │   │ val:  4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘

┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  2   │   │ val:  3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

In the first iteration of the loop, the first `if` condition is true, and so `list.next = list1` gets executed. This leads to the following:

```
head list
  ↓   ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val:  0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
list1    │ 
  ↓      ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  1   │   │ val:  4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘

┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  2   │   │ val:  3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

The next statement assigns a different node reference to `list1` with `list1 = list1.next`:

```
head list
  ↓   ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val:  0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
         │      list1
         ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  1   │   │ val:  4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘

┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  2   │   │ val:  3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

The last statement in the first iteration of the loop, moves the `list` reference, with `list = list.next`, which means `head` and `list` no longer reference the same node; and they will never be the same reference again:

```
head
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val:  0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
list     │      list1
  ↓      ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  1   │   │ val:  4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘

┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  2   │   │ val:  3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

In the second iteration of the loop, we get into the else block, and there we set `list.next = list2`:

```
head
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val:  0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
list     │      list1
  ↓      ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  1   │   │ val:  4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  2   │   │ val:  3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

Then `list1 = list1.next` will lead to:

```
head
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val:  0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
list     │      list1
  ↓      ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  1   │   │ val:  4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  2   │   │ val:  3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
                  ↑
                 list2
```

And again, the final statement of this second iteration, will move `list`:

```
head
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val:  0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
         │      list1
         ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  1   │   │ val:  4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  2   │   │ val:  3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑               ↑
list            list2
```

And so the process continues,... Never is `head` moving, but `list` is. When the loop exits, the situation will be this:

```
head
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val:  0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
         │                 list1 == null
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val:  1   │   │ val:  4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼                ▲
┌───────────┐   ┌─────────│─┐
│ val:  2   │   │ val:  3 │ │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──┘ │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
                  ↑        
                list       list2 == null
```

The return value is `head.next`, which indeed is the reference to the first node (with value 1) of the merged list.

I hope this clarified it.